# Dotted circle in true type font character?

Tags: fonts

Can anybody mention the name of the 'dotted circle portion' used in true type font characters( Example  ൌ  -   character code=U+0D4C )Can I edit that portion using any font creator software? I am doing this for proper rendering it in android Jelly bean Os

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dotted circle, used as a placeholder in composition, is called ["DOTTED CIRCLE"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25cc/index.htm), code U+25CC.

Using [U+0D4C from your example](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0D4C/index.htm): this character is a Malayalam vowel. In Unicode parlance it is a "Spacing Combining Mark" which means that it needs to be combined with another character to be "complete". When represented in its incomplete state, the dotted circle is used to indicate the relative position of the missing part(s).

Answer (score 1):

It's the 'DOTTED CIRCLE' code=U+25CC. Check [Unicode charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts).
You can edit it in [Fontforge](http://fontforge.org) if you want a multi-platform free font editor.